# How can I reference an external javascript library on an html page saved in amazon s3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a web app where html pages are created in an amazon s3 bucket. These html pages reference javascript with . where should I put the javascript source files in order for this to be rendered correctly with the javascript? Should I put them in the same bucket in that amazon s3 account? Would the html pages be rendered faster if the source files were in a static assets folder of my web app? If I am putting them in the amazon s3 bucket, how should I reference them; by path relative to the bucket or by the absolute full domain path given by amazon?

edit: I got it working with the following javascript ex:

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="display.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="Click Me!">
</body>
</html>
```

display.js:

```
function popup() {
alert("Hello World")
}
```

Comment: Your function will never fire and should be producing errors.  Remove everything but your call to document.write().  You should be able to see whether the file is being loaded in the dev tools of your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using relative paths will be much more efficient for resolving the javascript resource links locally to the server.  Using the public URL generated by Amazon will require DNS lookup and resolution, which takes time.

Comment: Ok so I should keep the java script source files in the amazon s3 bucket? How can I reference them with paths? I have edited the question above with what I tried (but didn't work)

Comment: If your resources are in the same folder as your HTML files, your path will be "someFile.js".  If in the root, "/someFile.js".  If in a "scripts" folder in the root, "/scripts/someFile.js".  Etc.